# How to use Npgsql in ASP.NET Boilerplate Core 2.0 template?

Tags: postgresql, migration, npgsql, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I have spent many hours trying to use PostgreSQL with ASP.NET Boilerplate Core 2.x + Module Zero (which looks awesome!).

1. I added `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` & `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design` dependencies to `myApp.EntityFrameworkCore`.
2. I also changed the connection string and I use `builder.UseNpgsql` instead of `builder.UseSqlServer` in `myappDbContextConfigurer.cs`.

As a new project, I started with `Npgsql v2.0.0`. But after a few problems, I found that this release has some issues. So I returned to the `1.1.1` release.

I'm pretty sure this part works fine. The next step is to delete all existing migrations and reload them:

- `Add-Migration "Initial_Migrations"`
- `Add-Migration "AbpZero_Initial"`

When I do the first one, I get an error:

> Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' does not have an implementation.

I found a beginning of the solution here (6th post): https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?t=5304&p=13013

The post seems a little bit outdated and I don't know where to implement `NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator` (I mean, in which project).

Thank you for reading this post, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Npgsql v1.1.1` targets `.NETStandard 1.3`, which is incompatible with `ABP for .NET Core 2.x`.

Comment: Thank you @aaron :)

Comment: You're welcome. Does that mean you got it to work with `Npgsql v2.0.0`?

Comment: No... I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve your issue with the Abp Template (v3.4.0 .NET core + mvc + modulezero) you have to :

- Uninstall the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- add Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (2.0.0) & Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design (1.1.1)
- Drop ALL files in the "Migrations" directory (Project "EntityFrameworkCore/Migrations")

There're other minors changes pointed [here](https://github.com/JbmOnGitHub/changeDbInAspnetboilerplate/blob/master/abptemplate_3_4_0_NETcore_mvc_modulezero.md).

Comment: Member for 2 years and 7 months on SO, with 0 questions and this drew you out to post your first answer? Nice :)

Comment: Could you explain why the downgrade is required?

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeDuke ! 
Everything looks good, tables are created and the project compiles.

I'm now able to go to the swagger view, even if I still have a warning when I run the migration... 

    An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. 
    Continuing without the application service provider. Error: 42P01: relationship « AbpEditions » does not exist

Comment: @aaron : Thanks. Previously, without this downgrade, i was not able to execute the database migration instructions. But after a new test, this step is not necessary. (My previous answer is updated now)

Comment: https://github.com/JbmOnGitHub/changeDbInAspnetboilerplate/blob/master/abptemplate_3_4_0_NETcore_mvc_modulezero.md works great